# Изменение текста кнопки при нажатии

Tags: ajax, javascript

Всем привет.
Наткнулся на такую проблему. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, она меняла свой текст на число нажатий на неё. То есть допустим на кнопке написано "Нажми меня", нажали один раз, на кнопке "1", еще раз - "2" и т.д. Это нужно сделать с помощью аякса, чтобы страница не перезагружалась. Помогите пожалуйста с этой задачей.

Comment: а зачем ajax? можно и чистым javascript

Comment: Нужно именно Ajax по заданию

Comment: @slavqache, странные у вас задания. Тогда это еще нужно серверный обработчик писать. На чистом js вот так http://jsfiddle.net/LS3Ff/

Comment: Просто нужно будет потом прицепить это так, что при нажатии кнопки N раз, мы получаем в корзине N экземпляров товара, которому принадлежит кнопка.

Comment: @slavqache, вы искали в интернете материалы как делать корзину на ajax-e ?

Comment: Нет, не искал

Comment: @slavqache, так попробуйте поискать. вот даже сайт подскажу где искать - http://google.com (сарказм)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, что вам на чистом JS надо? Тогда как-то так:

```
var xhr
,   button = document.getElementById('button'); // кнопка

button.onclick = function(){
    // создаем объект XMLHttpRequest
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// нормальные браузеры
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// IE6, IE5  - ну, мало ли ))
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open('POST','/path/to/handler.php',true); // метод передачи данных, путь и асинхронность (true/false)
    xhr.send('data1=Val1&data2=Val2'); // передаваемые значения
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        // если всё гуд
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            // в ответе - инкрементирование значение
            button.innerHTML = 'Кликнули ' + xhr.responseText + ' раз';
        }
    }
}
```

**(!*)** Если это учебное задание, то как бы всё понятно. А вообще, все эти операции лишние для таких задач, которые вы описали, но об этом вам как бы уже в комментариях сказали. Просто, чтоб вы учитывали это на будущее для реальных проектов